# Move the cursor to the next field and not submitting the form on enter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

what im trying to do is that when i press enter key the focus(cursor) moves to the next input field, and im getting that. in the code below i've set the submit of form false when enter is press so that the form would not submitted on enter. but as a result the form is not even submitted when i click on the submit button.
All i need is on enter my cursor moves to the next input field and the form will submit on click on the button. i hope it will make sense to you..

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.username').keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         var index = $('.username').index(this) + 1;
         $('.username').eq(index).focus();
     }
 });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="test">
<form method="POST" id="form">
<input type="text" class="username" onkeypress="sheikh(event)">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="username">
</form>
</div>
<script>
function sheikh(e){
var key;
if(e.which == 13){
    document.getElementById("form").onsubmit=function (){
    return false;
}
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("form").onsubmit=function (){
    return true;
}

        }


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have tried `if (e.which === 13) { e.preventDefault() ........`?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.username').keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.which === 13) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var index = $('.username').index(this) + 1;
         $('.username').eq(index).focus();
     }
 });
  

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="test">
<form method="POST" action="http://google.es" id="form">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="text" class="username">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"  class="username">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah its kind of working exactly like i want... But i cant type anything in the input fields..whats that about???

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. I edit the answer, now `preventDefault()` is only executed inside the if statement that detects enter key.

Comment: the solution works perfectly. but what about submitting the form on enter when last input is reached?

Comment: @ghulam_ali easy, you must detect if it's the last input (aka the last `index` number), and apply `$('form').submit();`  on that condition.

Answer (score 0):

**Change the input submit button as button type** which helps you to avoid so many unwanted js codes,  try the following code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".username:first").focus();
$('.username').keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
    if(!($(this).prop('nodeName')=="BUTTON")){
    e.preventDefault(); 

         var index = $('.username').index(this) + 1;
         $('.username').eq(index).focus();
     }
     }

 });

});
</script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div class="test">
    <form method="POST" action="http://www.google.com" id="form">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <button type="submit" value="submit" class="username">submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: same mistake as above..due to preventdefault.i cant write anaything in the input fields

Comment: script is edited please check it , now the preventdefault will fired only when we press the enter button